# Reading a 1D barcode regardless of Orientation

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to use ZXing to read 1D barcodes and want to be able to read the barcode no matter the orientation since I am assuming the person may not be looking at the image. I noticed that ZXing can read the barcode up to 45 degrees. Is there a reason it doesn't test both orientations of the image, and is it possible to make it do this?

If not are there alternatives that can?

Comment: Only way to make this work would be to rotate image data in all possible ways, in real time, and then feed it to zxing.

Comment: `I am assuming the person may not be looking at the image.` you are asking them to point the camera at the barcode and line it up within the box on the screen. why would you assume they aren't looking at the image? It is going to be rather difficult to make anything work if your users are unwilling to pay any attention. Anywho there are instructions floating around to rotate the scan activity by 9 degrees but even with that you get either/or, but not both. Fwiw though BarcodeScaner+ has a setting that allows the screen to auto rotate which sort of allows you to scan both orientations.

Comment: (BS+ still only scans near 0 and 180 degrees rotation, like the original. It's just that the UI can rotate.) The use case might be a kind of kiosk installation where the user does not see the camera view but holds a product up to a camera.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is just that 99.9% of the time people scan a barcode in its natural orientation (or upside down). Scanning for vertical barcodes would usually just be a waste of time, when you could be getting on to another frame to scan. But it's easy to do, just add an extra chunk of code to rotate and re-scan the image.

@user117 it is not necessary to try all orientations. Any rotation for which a horizontal line still passes through the whole barcode works. You would only have to try additional rotations to cover cases beyond those, and it turns out that 4 would be the most that are needed to cover any orientation.